# Best way to link a user to their data in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase for authentication and Cloud Firestore as a Database in my app. To link a user to their data a created a Users collection and each document name is a UserId that I get from Firebase Auth. My problem is if a user creates an account using email and password but then signs in using the same email but with Google Authentication instead, the Google Auth overwrites the Email and Password Authentication and the UserId changes.

Comment: Did you enable multiple registrations with same Email but different providers?

Comment: I thought of that but won't that change the original user id?

Comment: To be honest I never experienced a behaviour that you explain in your question. Usualy you need to link a Google Account to a Firebase user if he already was registered using Email. Even if it is possible it would just add another provider data to the user and not change the Firebase User uid. Can you somehow explain or show us how the uid changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not overwrite the email/password account. Indeed both will still exist if you check the user list in the console.

What happens here is that logging in with a different provider generates a separate set of credentials. So a new User ID is created. They are different credentials and only the warm body sitting at the keyboard knows if they happen to be owned by the same fleshbag of DNA and water.

Note that you can [link accounts together](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking). So if you want to treat providers who share an email address as the same user, you can check the email accounts and ask the user to link them by signing into each account during a single session.

Comment: when I check the authentication page in firebase theres is only the google account and not the email/password

Comment: I just tested this and it's working spiffy. See [here](https://kato-auth-test.stackblitz.io/) (create both accounts and click the sign in buttons interchangeably; they both exist). You may need to go [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers) and find the section at the bottom to allow multiple accounts per email address.